# PowerShell 7 on Linux, using Certificate to Authenticate to Azure

Tags: linux, azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I am not that experienced with Linux, so bear with me :-)
I am beginning to use the VSC Remote Development extension to connect to a Azure based Linux VM for PowerShell scripting purposes - works like a charm.

But I would like to have some easy way of handling certificates, using to authenticate connections to Azure Resource Manager (using Connect-AzAccount and a SPN in Azure AD).

I consider using the Azure KeyVault for Linux extension, which handle the cerificate distribution nicely.
On windows, the certificates end up in the personal certificate store and are directly usable. On Linux however, they end up in /var/lib/.. as PEM files.
So how do I get them "usable" in the easiest possible way..?

Thanks in advance for suggestions and ideas
\Jesper

Comment: Since you use Azure linux VM, why do not use Azure MSI to login Azure?

Comment: The reason for not using MSI is basically two things: The certificate based SPN are already there and we need cross tenant connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [Key Vault virtual machine extension for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/key-vault-linux) is an easy way to go. The VM extension would require system or user-managed identity to be assigned to authenticate to the Key Vault. See [How to authenticate to Key Vault and assign a Key Vault access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-portal-windows-vm). You can use this identity to authenticate to any service that supports Azure AD authentication, without having credentials in your code.

Your observed certificate URLs should be of the form `https://myVaultName.vault.azure.net/secrets/myCertName`.

Comment: The extension works like a charm, rock solid. Ant certificates are arriving on the Linux box. However to get them ready to use, I seem to need to do something like this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8658#issuecomment-468792648 which I would rather avoid if possible